# jQuery counter stop at zero and if zero show replace HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I checked in stackoverflow for a solution to this but after trying a few full pages of results, I figured I'd just ask ;)

**Sum-up:**
I have a mini-game where I am offering hints when an item on a list is clicked. There will be a bunch of items on the list but they can only use 3 hints. The text will change from "you have 3 hints" to "2 hints" then "0 hints" When they use all the hints and get to zero nothing else should be counted and the directions under the hint text should change.

**What I have working:**
I have a counter that counts down from 3 when an item on the list is clicked and the "You Have X Hints" updates.

**What I need help with:**
The counter doesn't stop at zero, it just keeps going down into negative numbers if oyu keep clicking the list items. How do I stop it a zero and disable the counter?

The directions paragraph should only change when they reach zero but it shows after first click. How do I only make it show at zero?

Thanks for your help!
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/ophyfd8t/2/

Code below:

JS

```
var counter = 3;

$('.itemList li').on('click', function () {
  counter--;

  if (counter == 0) {
      $('.xHints').html(counter + ' Hints');
  } else {
      $('.xHints').html(counter + ' Hints');
      $('.directions').html('New directions');
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="itemWrapper">
   <ul class="itemList">
       <li>cat</li>
       <li>mouse</li>
       <li>cheese</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="hintBox"> <span class="youHave">You Have</span>
<span class="xHints">3 Hints</span>

    <p class="directions">Use a hint by clicking on a name in the list.</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the counter has reached zero already before you decrement it.
You can also simplify your code a bit:

```
if(counter > 0) {
    counter--;

    if(counter == 0)
        $('.directions').html('New directions');

    $('.xHints').html(counter + ' Hints');
}
```

Comment: Oh nice!! Thanks so much :) Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/7f24qug0/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do equal to or less than zero. Because the counter can get below zero.

```
var counter = 3;

$('.itemList li').on('click', function () {
  counter--;

  if (counter <= 0) {
      // This will occur once counter reaches zero, or negative numbers
      $('.xHints').html(counter + ' Hints');
      // If you don't want counter to go below zero, you could reset counter = 1 here 
      counter = 1;
  } else {
      // This will occur for all times counter is above 0
      $('.xHints').html(counter + ' Hints');
      $('.directions').html('New directions');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried <= 0 and it did not seem to stop it. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/1fhcb8d1/1/

Comment: Added some comments to help explain

Comment: Hey Drew, Thanks for posting this. I went ahead and tried it out. I found that the counter needed to be "counter=1" for it to work properly with this solution. Otherwise it would go to -1 and then stop. I appreciate you posting this. Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/1fhcb8d1/2/